# remove file name in IE using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I tried executing `$('#files').val('');` in IE, but it doesn't clear the file input field.

```
$('#uploadimgdiv').html('');
var fil1 = document.getElementById("files");
$('#fil1').val('');
document.getElementById("files").value ='';
document.getElementById("uploadimghid").value ='';
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Trying to clear the file input field ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
$('#files').val('');
$('#uploadimghid').val('');
```

By setting `.val()` to an empty string, jQuery will empty the fields referenced in the selector.